# Scrapy loader data "disappearing" at input processor

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm using Scrapy to extract certain price data from a website. The site's data always looks like:

```
Amazon Price: x円
```

or,

```
Search Price: x円
```

where `x` is a currency-formatted number without a decimal portion. I have a regular expression I'm using to extract this field, inside an item loader:

```
loader.add_css(Product..re(r'(?<=[(Amazon Price)(Search Price)]:\s)[,\d]+(?=円)')
```

Every test case I have run from the website I'm scraping shows that this regular expression works. In my item class I have:

```
price = Field(input_processor = Compose(lambda v: print(v), Join(separator = '')),
    output_processor = Compose(TakeFirst(), lambda v: print(v), lambda v: v.replace(',', ''), lambda v: int(v)),
    serializer = int)
```

where the print statements are being used for debugging output (if anyone knows a better way, I'd appreciate hearing about it). Since this field can be run from multiple spiders, where some might assign a list of integers-as-strings to `price`, I am using `Join(separator = '') to collate them in that case. I have verified that this works as well. In output, I am using`TakeFirst()`to get what should be the only element on the array, removing any commas with`replace(',', '') and casting the result to an `int`. I have verified that all of this code works.

Now, the reason for my question:

The first `print` statement in the input processor only ever shows a value of `[]`.

I have checked the pages which show this output and have verified that they do not behave this way in testing. I also have no middlewares installed into the project and my pipelines should only be running after the item is loaded. So, as I am at my wit's end, please can someone explain why this is happening?

Additional points for feedback on my reg-ex because I think there should be a better way but haven't been able to figure one out yet.

Comment: Do you check source HTML (`Ctrl+U`) ? Can you post it here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem and in the process I found a couple issues that I think would help anyone who's new to scrapy. The first is that `print` doesn't actually return anything so when you put it in `Compose` it will actually halt execution, which was the first problem with what I was doing.

The second problem is that I was trying to pass `loader` between helper methods on my spider. This is a problem because when you do that, the item loader will assume the response you created it with so using `loader.add_css` will not work because your CSS selector will be parsed against the response you used to create the item loader in the first place, which is probably not what you want. What I did was create a middleware that zipped all my partial items together into a coherent response.